# Сеть в vmware

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware

Ситуация такая:
Есть один шнурок интернета от провайдера, идет на маршрутизатор. Маршрутизатор дает сеть 192.168.1.0/24 Поставил vmware, на неё win server, делаю определенные задания для себя. Проблема: назначил ей ip 10.0.0.11. Внимание, вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы win server пинговался (виделся) из 192.168.0.*? Или хотя бы сделать так, чтобы два win servera на виртуалке имели одну внутреннюю сеть, как если бы они вместе "питались" от маршрутизатора? Ну и, соответсвтенно, могли пинговать друг друга.

Comment: Всё работает. Как-то настроил)

Comment: Можно закрыть вопрос))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

использовать host-only network в свойствах VM

Comment: Да у меня и мост сейчас отлично работает:) Но всё равно спасибо:)

Answer (score 0):

Настройте одну виртуальную сетёвку сетевым мостом, вторую виртуальную (на том же сервере) тоже. На одной сетёвке пропишите параметры провайдера, а для второй - локалку. На втором сервере можно указать только локальный адрес и в качестве шлюза - IP первого сервера. Тогда на основном компьютере будут пинговаться оба сервера и будет между ними сетка.

Comment: Мне не нужна работа сервера шлюзом/маршрутизатором, я же написал - два от маршруты, соответственно, две машины. Ну и опять же, как я уже написал - я уже всё давно настроил.